# RedirectToAction to a controller in different area not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller called Controller1 , which is inside an area called Area1. I am trying to redirect to another controller Controller2, in a different area called Area2 using the following code.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller2", new { area = "Area2" });
```

this code was working fine 3 months before. I don't know what got changed in my system, and this code does not work now. Also one thing I noticed is that when redirecting to a controller within the same area, it is working fine without any issues .The issue is with when we try to redirect to a controller in a different area.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Update : the syntax is correct, which I checked. its nothing related to double quotes for Area name

Comment: Since there are unbalanced `"`s there, it's "difficult" to believe that this code ever worked fine.

Comment: try putting area name in quotes(string) `RedirectToAction("Index, "Controller2", new { area = "Area2" })`

Comment: **Count** the quote marks. There were 3, there are now 5. If you're not even showing us *actual* code, what do you expect us to do?

Comment: @Damien : the syntax is correct, which I checked. its nothing related to double quotes for Area name.

Comment: If the code you're looking at compiles, it's *not* the code in the question. We can't help you when the only line of code you're showing us *isn't* the actual line of code you're working with.

Comment: @Damien : Sorry I forgot to add the " in the question initially, which I updated now.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE]

Comment: this is the actual code : return RedirectToAction("Index, "Controller2", new { area = "Area2" });

Comment: that line of code cannot possibly work, you haven't closed the quotes on Index ...

Comment: @AvinashKarat - that code contains 5 (unescaped) quote marks and will not compile on any version of the C# compiler I know of.

Comment: @Damien : Sorry, I corrected the question again. please check now.

Comment: Yes, we now have a line of code that may compile. However, you've destroyed *my* faith that it's in any way related to a line of code in your code base that is actually causing a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct " s in your code:-

```
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller2", new { area = "Area2" });
```

Comment: the syntax is correct, which I checked. its nothing related to double quotes for Area name

Answer (score 0):

this solution should be working :

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller2", new { area = "Area2" });
```

**Update** : Add " to Index

Comment: the syntax is correct, which I checked. its nothing related to double quotes for Area name

Comment: how can this be correct when Index is not wrapped inside double quotes correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the question again. please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Use another method like 
Sring url=string.Format("/Area2/index")
return Redirect(url);